# id cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

Quisiera saber porque sale estos errores:

```
An error occurred at line: 383 in the jsp file: /cinema.jsp
id cannot be resolved to a variable
380: %>
381:    <tr>
382:     <td>
383:     <%=id%>
384:     </td>
385:     <td>
386:     <%=rs.getString(2)%>


An error occurred at line: 421 in the jsp file: /cinema.jsp
id cannot be resolved to a variable
418:     <%=rs.getString(8)%>
419:     </td>
420:     <td onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"  onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent'">
421:     <a href="cinema.jsp?mode=delete_film&id=<%=id%>">Óäàëèòü</a><br>
422:     <a href="cinema.jsp?mode=order_tickets&id=<%=id%>">Ïðîäàòü áèëåòû</a><br>
423:     </td>
424:    </tr>


An error occurred at line: 422 in the jsp file: /cinema.jsp
id cannot be resolved to a variable
419:     </td>
420:     <td onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='yellow'"  onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='transparent'">
421:     <a href="cinema.jsp?mode=delete_film&id=<%=id%>">Óäàëèòü</a><br>
422:     <a href="cinema.jsp?mode=order_tickets&id=<%=id%>">Ïðîäàòü áèëåòû</a><br>
423:     </td>
424:    </tr>
425: 


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:536)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:364)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
```

cinema.jsp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los JSPs acaban convertidos automáticamente en *servlets*, que luego se compilan.

Cuando haces

```
<%=id%>
```

Acaba siendo en el servlet

```
out.println(id); // out es una variable predefinida que es la salida del `response`.
```

Y el problema es, sencillamente, que no has definido ninguna variable `id`. Por ejemplo, si hicieras:

```
 <% int id = 42; %>
 <%=id%>
```

ya te compilaría.

Por supuesto, luego tienes que decidir TÚ qué quieres que signifique `id` y cómo obtiene su valor.